# How to put a text in the middle of two rows?

Tags: tables

In fact, I would like to write the contents of the two last columns in the middle of the two rows of the first column. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}


\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % centered 'p' col.
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{framed}  % Framing content
\usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip}\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c } 
\toprule
\makecell{Case of each letter}  & first signification  & second 
singnification \\   
\midrule
S with T\\ T with U&  L &  A   &  \\
Q with X\\ X with W & V & B    &     \\
Z with W\\ W with Y& M  & C &   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}
\captionof{table}{example}
\label{tab:SC}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

for example : L and A must be in the middle of S with T & T with U and also I want a space between the row 1 and 2 and between row 2 and 3 
[image]

Comment: I have edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
%\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % centered 'p' col.
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{framed} % Framing content
\usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip}\usepackage{booktabs,multirow, caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c }
\toprule
\makecell{Case of \\ each letter} & \makecell{first\\ signification }& \makecell{second\\
singnification} \\
\midrule
\makecell{S with T\\ T with U}& L & A & \\
\addlinespace
\makecell{Q with X\\ X with W }& V & B & \\
\addlinespace
\makecell{Z with W\\ W with Y}& M & C & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\vspace{\dimexpr0.5\baselineskip-\parskip}
\captionof{table}{example}
\label{tab:SC}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @twimo: Unrelated, but it's typographically more correct to have table captions *above* tables (because tables may spread across pages).

Comment: How can I make them above the tables ?

Comment: Writing `captionof` just before \begin{tabular}` (unless the `elsarticle` class forbids it!). In this case, load the `caption` package to have a decent spacing between caption and table (latex does not swap the values of `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip` by itself).

Comment: captionof before \begin{tabular} worked well I was trying with \usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top} Thank you @Bernard